# Lag en un input de tipo text

Tags: php, html

Estoy teniendo un problema de lag en tiempo real en un input de tipo text de un formulario. Con lag me refiero que al escribir, desde que pulsas una letra hasta que se visualiza en pantalla pasan unas milésimas de segundo, y si escribes rápido le cuesta más y es más notorio el problema.

El código que uso es el siguiente:

```
<form <?php if($user != "null") { echo "style='background: #" . $usuario_color['color_fondo'] . ";'";} ?> class="hilo_wrapper" action="crear_hilo.php?foro=<?php echo str_replace(" ", "%",$foro) ?>&subforo=<?php echo $subforo ?>"  method="post">
                <div class="data_hilo">
                    <input <?php echo "style='border-color: #" . $usuario_color['color_principal'] . ";' onmouseover=\"this.style.boxShadow='inset 0 1px 1px #" . $usuario_color['color_secundario'] . ", 0 0 8px #" . $usuario_color['color_secundario'] . "'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.boxShadow='inset 0 0 0 transparent,0 1px 1px transparent'\"" ?> type="text" name="asunto" placeholder="Asunto:" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['vista_previa'])) { echo $asunto; } else if (isset($_POST['crear_hilo'])) { echo $asunto;} else if (isset($_POST['guardar_borrador'])) { echo $asunto;} else if (!empty($info_borradores)) { echo $info_borradores['asunto'];} ?>">
                </div>

                <?php if ($usuario_color['administrador'] == 1): ?>
                    <div style='width:100%; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center' class="">
                        <input style='width: 20px;' type="checkbox" name="fijar" value="1" <?php if($fijar == 1 AND isset($_POST['vista_previa'])) { echo "checked";} else if (!empty($info_borradores) AND $info_borradores['hilo_fijado'] == 1) { echo "checked";} else if (isset($_POST['guardar_borrador']) AND $fijar == 1) { echo "checked";} ?>><p style='width:200px'>Marca la casilla para fijar el hilo</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style='width:100%; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center' class="">
                        <input style='width: 20px;' type="checkbox" name="relevante" value="1" <?php if($relevante == 1 AND isset($_POST['vista_previa'])) { echo "checked";} else if (!empty($info_borradores) AND $info_borradores['hilo_relevante'] == 1) { echo "checked";} else if (isset($_POST['guardar_borrador']) AND $relevante == 1) { echo "checked";} ?>><p style='width:200px'>Marca como hilo relevante</p>
                    </div>
                    <div style='width:100%; display:flex; flex-wrap: wrap;justify-content: center' class="">
                        <input style='width: 20px;' type="checkbox" name="cerrar" value="1" <?php if($cerrar == 1 AND isset($_POST['vista_previa'])) { echo "checked";} else if (!empty($info_borradores) AND $info_borradores['hilo_cerrado'] == 1) { echo "checked";} else if (isset($_POST['guardar_borrador']) AND $cerrar == 1) { echo "checked";} ?>><p style='width:200px'>Marcar para cerrar el hilo</p>
                    </div>
                <?php endif; ?>

                <?php

                if (!empty($aviso_borrador)) {
                    echo $aviso_borrador;
                }
                ?>

                <?php require 'emoticonos.php' ?>

                <div class="botones_crear_hilo">
                    <?php require 'botones_textarea.php' ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-100">
                    <textarea <?php echo "style='border-color: #" . $usuario_color['color_principal'] . ";' onmouseover=\"this.style.boxShadow='inset 0 1px 1px #" . $usuario_color['color_secundario'] . ", 0 0 8px #" . $usuario_color['color_secundario'] . "'\" onmouseout=\"this.style.boxShadow='inset 0 0 0 transparent,0 1px 1px transparent'\"" ?> id="txt1" name="texto_hilo" placeholder="Texto:"><?php if (isset($_POST['vista_previa'])) { echo $vista_previa;} else if (isset($_POST['crear_hilo'])) {echo $texto;} else if (isset($_POST['guardar_borrador'])) { echo $texto_sin_etiquetas_html;} else if (!empty($info_borradores)) { echo $info_borradores['texto_sin_etiquetas'];} ?></textarea>

                    <div class="col-emoticonos-enviar">
                        <input <?php if($user != "null") { echo "style='background: #" . $usuario_color['color_principal'] . ";'";} ?> type="submit" name="vista_previa" value="Vista previa">
                        <input <?php if($user != "null") { echo "style='background: #" . $usuario_color['color_principal'] . ";'";} ?> type="submit" name="guardar_borrador" value="Guardar borrador">
                        <input <?php if($user != "null") { echo "style='background: #" . $usuario_color['color_principal'] . ";'";} ?> type="submit" name="crear_hilo" value="Crear hilo">
                    </div>
                </div>


                <?php

                if (!empty($errores)) {
                    echo "<p class='errores'>" . $errores .  "</p>";
                } else if (isset($_POST['guardar_borrador']) AND empty($errores)) {
                    echo "<p class='enviado'>Mensaje guardado en borradores correctamente</p>";
                }


                ?>


            </form>
```

He probado a quitarle los estilos y el problema persiste. No hace ninguna comprobación en tiempo real, sólo cuando se pulsa sobre uno de los 3 botones que hay. Además, el `textarea` funciona perfectamente sin lag ni nada y tiene más cosas asociadas como botones y emoticonos. No sé a qué puede deberse.

Comment: Puedes usar la consola de desarrollo del navegador y comprobar si hay algún evento asociado a dicho elemento o un evento de tipo `key` asociado al elemento o al body (event delegate) ?? Estás usando algún plugin, librería o addon javascript?

Comment: @Muriano ¿Cómo puedo comprobar eso? Sólo tengo javascript asociado al testare, para los botones y emoticonos más que nada.

Comment: Con la consola de desarrollo de chrome, por ejemplo. En la pestaña `Elements`, puedes seleccionar un elemento de tu web con `Ctrl + Shift + c`,  y en el panel de información del elemento, la pestaña `Event Listeners` te dará una idea sobre si hay eventos ligados al elemento.

Comment: @Muriano Me aparece vacío pero no puede ser, el textarea también me aparece vacío y tiene javascript asociado. Me he fijado también que en Firefox y Chrome parece ir bien, es en Safari donde me genera el lag.

Comment: No pongas el código PHP, pon el código HTML generado para que tengamos un [mcve] y podamos reproducir el problema.